# Do I need to type every time : sudo gem install cocoapods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Do I need to type every time I open a new project : sudo gem install cocoapods , to install Cocoapods , or is it a one time thing ? and next time just get the project cd and install pod ?

Comment: Only one time, for a new project you just run pod install

Comment: No, `sudo gem install cocoa pods` is to install cocoa pods. To add a pod in new project you have to write `pod init`. It will give you the `pod file` and then you can do `pod install`.

Comment: It's an "app". Once you installed it (with `gem` which is the "installer tool"), you can call it (with `pod something`) every time you want. It might need an update from time to time too.

Comment: You can use Swift Package Manager instead of Cocoapods

Comment: Most of the pods doesnt support Swift Package Manager , so i wont recommend it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaPods is a dependency manager for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects.

If you don't have installed cocoa pods earlier, to install cocoa pods into your machine execute the following command.
`sudo gem install cocoa pods`

To add the installed dependency manager to your project use the following command.
`pod init`.

This will create a file called podfile in your project directory. Include the dependencies in the file appropriately and execute `pod install` to install the dependencies.